# Are we sure that electric “monopoles” are not just ends of an “Electrical Dirac String”?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, magnetic-monopoles, duality, dirac-string

The Dirac String is used to model magnetic monopoles. So how are we sure that physical electric “monopoles” are not in fact the ends of an “Electrical Dirac String” produced by a solenoid carrying a current of “magnetic charges”? Could an electrical version of the Dirac String be at the root of the existence of electric monopoles?

Comment: This episode of PBS Space Time may help - [Dirac Strings Debunked](https://johnmarkmorris.com/2021/10/13/dirac-strings-debunked/). It doesn't seem to debunk them as much as discuss the physics around them.

Comment: There is a thought experiment on my part in which I was able to create a model of the electric and magnetic field as well as the EM radiation based on only two assumed particles. Amusing thought process and - I warn you - bad writing style. See [Complex one-dimensional structures of space](https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one_dimensional_structures_of_space)